# Embedding recent post column of WordPress blog in asp.net website

Tags: php, asp.net, .net, wordpress

I want to show latest post of My WordPress blog in my ASP.Net website. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Use webservice or rss feeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you search for XML-RPC_WordPress_API.

you get detail information from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_wp)